# How do I create an array or an OrderedCollection of dates between two days in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

I have two dates and I would like to create an array or and OrderedCollection between them. 
I would also like to be able to compare this array/OrderedCollection with another one in a condition.

I have this code which gives me the span between the two date. However Timespan uses aDateAndTime as input. The span at the end, would give me the desired span.

```
period: anIneger startFrom: aString
  |startDate span |
  startDate := Date fromString: aString. 
  span := Timespan starting: startDate duration: anInteger days. 
  span every: 1 days do: [ :each | Transcript show: each; cr ]. 
  ^span
```

I am not very good in Pharo or Object-Oriented programming and I am trying to learn, sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to express a timespan? Have a look at the `Timespan` class.

Comment: The rules of SO require you to try something before asking a question. Browse the class `Array` and look for methods that could do what you want. Then come back and refine your question showing evidence of your effort.

Comment: You can click the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50721931/edit) under your question to update it.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia, sorry about breaking the rules. I 've updated the post.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Just note that to iterate on the _dates_ in the `span` you need to replace `each` with `each asDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think, this is, what are you looking for:

`period: anInteger startFrom: aString
        | startDate |
        startDate := Date fromString: aString.
        ^ (1 to: anInteger) collect: [:each | startDate addDays: each - 1]`

Comment: Thank you so much.